# JMeter - using UDV for post json body

Tags: jmeter

Using JSR223 Sampler, I read contents of my payload file, appended ${loop} variable to its contents, and stored whole of payload data into a user defined variable "payloadAsString"(via vars.put())

Can I use this variable in my HTTP Request sampler's 'Body Data' section as ${payloadAsString} ?

By this, I am expecting the content stored in the variable, along with the 'loop' value in it, to be incremented,during run time.

please advise.

Comment: you can use, Did you give it a try?? facing any issues? If yes, what are they?

Comment: I did try that, the variable stores all of my payload, however the ${loop} variable inside it, does not get incremented with each iterations, when given as 'Body Data' for a HTTP Request. Suggest alternatives

Comment: please share your test plan (Screenshot) to further assist you.